# HTML entity code not displaying on MacOs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using html entities for previous and next page navigation on my web page . It will be displayed fine on Windows , Linux os but  Mac Os it display's as empty box . What's the problem and how can I fix this ?

CODE :

```
  &#9195;
```

Comment: can u show the real images of this code and now used this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the character, BLACK UP-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE' (U+23EB), appears in very few fonts. Apparently some systems that you tested it on have one of those fonts, the Mac system doesn’t have. Or maybe you use an embedded font, via `@font face`, in a manner that fails on Mac.

The character is very unsafe in www authoring and in data interchange. Added to Unicode recently (in version 6.0), it should not be expected to become widely supported in several years. Via font embedding, it might be possible to use it.

According to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23eb/fontsupport.htm the character appears in Everson Mono and Symbola only. However, Everson Mono has a wrong glyph for it (a left-pointing double triangle). On the other hand, Quivira contains it, too. These three fonts are all special fonts that are hardly included in any computer system by default; they must be separately downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can used to **HTML Entity (hex)** value code

i think this value code is `&#x23eb;`

more info about your code http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23eb/index.htm

Comment: Using hexadecimal vs. decimal character reference is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the OS. It's purely a matter of fonts.